# Disable wireplumber.service and autostart pulseaudio

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

Recently I'm having sound issues on Fedora 35. After booting I don't have any sound.

The output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*` is:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  root       1036 f.... alsactl
                     iljarotar   2160 F.... wireplumber
                     iljarotar   3209 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  root       1036 f.... alsactl
                     iljarotar   2160 F.... wireplumber
                     iljarotar   3209 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/seq:        iljarotar   2159 F.... pipewire
```

Typing `systemctl --user stop wireplumber.service` and restarting pulseaudio solves the problem. So I tried to disable wireplumber and enable pulseaudio but it doesn't seem to work. Right after booting wireplumber is running again. It's only two commands to type, but it becomes quite annoying to do this every time I start my computer.

The first time this occured was after installing ardour following this guide: https://ardour.org/building_linux.html and making an update. So I don't know for sure what caused it.

I would really appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Solved the problem by removing pulseaudio and installing pipewire-pulseaudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF YOU WANT REVERT TO PURE PULSEAUDIO**

1/ disable the service

```
systemctl --user disable wireplumber.service
```

2/ mask the service for dependency activation - mask is to prevent any kind of activation, even manual...

```
systemctl --user mask wireplumber.service
```

3/ & stop for current session if we want not use it before restart

```
systemctl --user stop wireplumber.service
```

4/ check if unit/service has no .socket or .timer which will trigger it - need to disable/mask those too

5/ restore pulseaudio

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.service

systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.socket
```

**TO FIX PIPEWIRE**

install package

pipewire-pulseaudio

Comment: I did install pipewire-pulseaudio in the end, which solved the issue. Thanks for the explanation!